# VueJS - data changes when I change const variable

Tags: javascript

I have a `participants` variable for `b-form-select` and I want to set `disabled = true` to option if option selected one of the other 2 selectboxes. Totally I have 3 selectboxes.

When I change the `par` variable, VueJS changes to `participants` variable. What's the problem?

```
acceptorsOptions(item){
    let par = this.participants;
    return par.map(participant => {
        let refusers = item.refusers.filter(refuser => refuser === participant.value);
        let abstentions = item.abstentions.filter(abstention => abstention === participant.value);
        if( refusers.length > 0 || abstentions.length > 0 )
            participant.disabled = true;
        return participant;
    });
},
refusersOptions(item){
    let par = this.participants;
    return par.map(participant => {
        let acceptors = item.acceptors.filter(acceptor => acceptor === participant.value);
        let abstentions = item.abstentions.filter(abstention => abstention === participant.value);
        if( acceptors.length > 0 || abstentions.length > 0 )
            participant.disabled = true;
        return participant;
    });
},
abstentionsOptions(item){
    let par = this.participants;
    return par.map(participant => {
        let refusers = item.refusers.filter(refuser => refuser === participant.value);
        let acceptors = item.acceptors.filter(acceptor => acceptor === participant.value);
        if( refusers.length > 0 || acceptors.length > 0 )
            participant.disabled = true;
        return participant;
    });
},
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because of using `this.participants` for every variable.

So you can solve your problem simply by cloning `this.participants` like this:

```
let par = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.participants));
```

You can read more about that: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) and [here](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects).

That will solve your problem.